# limit of sequence on primes

Tags: number-theory

Let $k>0$ be a natural number and  $P_i$ be ith prime number.
Let $P_l$ be the smallest prime number greater than $k$.
Prove that,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{i=l}^n\frac{P_{i+1}-k}{P_i}=\infty$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$\prod_i (1+\frac{P_{i+1}-P_i-k}{P_i})$$
Using partial summation show that $\sum_i (\frac{P_{i+1}-P_i-k}{P_i})^2$ converges so we are left with $$\sum_i\frac{P_{i+1}-P_i-k}{P_i} = 1+ \sum_i (\sum_{j \le i} P_{j+1}-P_j-k)(\frac{1}{P_i}-\frac{1}{P_{j+1}})$$

$$ \ge \sum_i (P_{i+1} - 2 - ik)(\frac{1}{P_i}-\frac{1}{P_{j+1}})\ge \sum_i C i \log i(\frac{1}{P_i}-\frac{1}{P_{j+1}})$$

$$ \ge  O(1)+C\sum_i ((i+1) \log (i+1) - i\log i)\frac{1}{P_i}$$

$$ \ge O(1)+\sum_i A\log(i)\frac{1}{i\log i} = \infty$$

where I used two partial summations and $P_i \ge c i \log i$